# Struts2 custom tag/template

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

I'm in a struts project. I wanted to create reusable custom tags.
So heres the thing, for example i have this set of struts UI tags:

```
<s:form action="some.action" namespace="/somenamespace">
    <s:textfield name="username" label="Username"/>
    <s:textfield name="pwd" label="Password" />
    <s:submit value="login"/>
</s:form>
```

Is it possible to come up with something like this to produce the same output instead of the code above:

```
<mycustomtag:login />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the  [tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/component.html) for this. An other way are [Templates](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/themes-and-templates.html) or creating your own custom Struts2 Tag Lib like other Plugins ([jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)/[Bootstrap](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-bootstrap/)).

Comment: I've done this. I created custom template and defined my own .tld file but I have some error. It says File "/custom-tags" not found. I placed my .tld file in the /META-INF as mentioned in this page [link](http://joshuajava.wordpress.com/2008/12/27/creating-custom-components-with-struts-2/). Did I miss something??

Comment: I got it. I just need to declare my custom taglib in the web.xml. Thanks a lot jogep!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using tag-files.

Here are some links:

- [Link 1](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/11/14/tagfiles.html)
- [Link 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html)